# I am trying to make a link popup a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, href, newsletter

So I have the script, its a subscriber popup, I want to write a link on a certain post that will allow the popup to fire from clicking the link

I know how to create java popups, The issue is how to get the code from the newsletter site into a link

Anyone?

Here is the code that needs to go in the link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us10.list-manage.com","uuid":"9277d2ea37fce583555bef789","lid":"4fcff7a4f6"}) })</script>
```

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` in your code

Comment: FYI Java !== JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to open the pop-up using [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), then modify the content of the pop-up using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

The HTML could be like this:

```html
<button onclick="openwindow()">Open Window</button>
```

or like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:openwindow()">Open Window</a>
```

And then the JS code/fucntion would be like this:

```js
var window_handler = null;

function openwindow() {
    window_handler = window.open();
    window_handler.document.write("<h1>AAA</h1>");
}
```

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9v7bzun/

---

In your particular case, replace the `<h1>AAA</h1>` part for your own code and it will be done:

```
function openwindow() {
    window_handler = window.open();
    window_handler.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us10.list-manage.com","uuid":"9277d2ea37fce583555bef789","lid":"4fcff7a4f6"}) })</script>');
}
```

Comment: ALvaro I am somewhat a noob to JS, i understand the basics but not the advanced stuff, All I want is when they click the "HREF" link it pushes the popup from the JS

Comment: Tell me what you don't understand from my solution, and I'll explain it better :)

Comment: Well I can see how the JS is written, are you saying that we create the popup link then add the rest into the "<h1>AAA</h1>" section, as in the entire script?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question to add the function code for your particular case

Comment: Javascript, its for a mailchimp signup form, normally its supposed to trigger on pageload, but I want to manually pop it up

Comment: Then the code above should do. Some pop-up blockers will stop `window.open()` if it's not triggered by a user action (on pageload), but it should be OK onclick.

Comment: Ok when I installed the code and clicked on the link it just brought me to the top of the page, like an anchor, here is what I put at the top of the page

Comment: <script>// <![CDATA[
function openPopUp() { require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us10.list-manage.com","uuid":"9277d2ea37fce583555bef789","lid":"4fcff7a4f6"}) }) }
// ]]></script>

Comment: are you using the function above?

Comment: I am inserting that first part into the body of the post code,

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Please create a CodePen or a JSFiddle to show your code.

Comment: I guess maybe its to difficult, I simply wanted users to click a text link to popup the subscriber popup, I did not think it would be this involved

Comment: The code is there, it's just 4 lines, and it's working (see the JSFiddle). If it's not working on your side, it could be for different reasons: there is a conflict with some other JS code, maybe it's not being applied correctly in the front-end, there may be some bug in it... check the JS console, and see what's failing. Without an insight to the whole code, it's impossible to know what is going wrong

Comment: Yes I see that, the java is being stripped out of the wordpress page for some reason